# Java - User-Input for If-Statement & several smaller questions

Tags: java, input, methods, return

I am practicing java for my programming exam in university and I am almost done with this program.

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Recording {
    public int height;
    public int diameter;
    public int weight;

    public Recording (int height, int diameter, int weight) {
        this.height = height;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.weight = weight;
    }   
}
```

and the one with all the action going on:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Leergut {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] recordings = new int[4];
        total(recordings);
        summary(recordings);
        int total = recordings[0]+recordings[1]+recordings[2]+recordings[3]+recordings[4];
        int count = recordings[0]*9+recordings[1]*10+recordings[2]*10+recordings[3]*8+recordings[4]*15;

        System.out.println("Type 0:"+recordings[0]+" pcs x 9c");
        System.out.println("Type 0:"+recordings[1]+" pcs x 10c");
        System.out.println("Type 0:"+recordings[2]+" pcs x 10c");
        System.out.println("Type 0:"+recordings[3]+" pcs x 8c");
        System.out.println("Type 0:"+recordings[4]+" pcs x 15c");
        System.out.println("total: "+total+"c ("+count+" pcs)");
        }

    public static int classify(Recording r) {
        if (r.height == 250 && r.diameter == 67 && r.weight == 365) {int code = 0; return code;}
        if (r.height == 300 && r.diameter == 80 && r.weight == 62) {int code = 1; return code;}
        if (r.height == 300 && r.diameter == 85 && r.weight == 152) {int code = 2; return code;}
        if (r.height == 250 && r.diameter == 67 && r.weight == 62) {int code = 3; return code;}
        if (r.height == 250 && r.diameter == 80 && r.weight == 152) {int code = 4; return code;}
        else { int code = -2; return code ;}
    }

    public static int deposit(int code) {
        int pfand;
            if(code == 0) {pfand = 9; return pfand;}
            if(code == 1) {pfand = 10; return pfand;}
            if(code == 2) {pfand = 10; return pfand;}
            if(code == 3) {pfand = 8; return pfand;}
            if(code == 4) {pfand = 15; return pfand;}
            else { pfand = 0; return pfand;}
    }

    public static int[] total(int[] recordings) throws IOException {
        int code = 5;
        while (code != -2) {
            Recording r = new Recording(System.in.read(), System.in.read(), System.in.read()); 
            code = Leergut.classify(r);
            int pfand = Leergut.deposit(code);
        } 
        if (code == -2) {
            System.out.println("FehlerCode -1");
        }
        return recordings;
    }

    public static int[] summary(int[] recordings) throws IOException {
        int code = 5;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int count3 = 0;
        int count4 = 0;
        int count5 = 0;

        while (code != -1) {
            Recording r = new Recording(System.in.read(), System.in.read(), System.in.read()); 
            code = Leergut.classify(r);

            if(code == 0) {count1++;}
            if(code == 1) {count2++;}
            if(code == 2) {count3++;}
            if(code == 3) {count4++;}
            if(code == 4) {count5++;}
        }

        recordings[0] = count1;
        recordings[1] = count2;
        recordings[2] = count3;
        recordings[3] = count4;
        recordings[4] = count5;

        return recordings;
    }
}
```

Now the task is to create those:

- `int classify(Recording r) ->` classify the input and or else return negative value
- `int deposit(int code) ->` calculate how much the bottle is worth or return 0
- `int[] total(Recording[] r) ->` get sum of the values, use deposit+ classify
  for invalid arguments, return null
- `int[] summary(Recording[] r) ->` get distribution how often each code comes up, index 0 is the first code and so on...
  for invalid arguments, return null

Now my problem is that I want to `System.in.read()` like this:

> 250, 67, 365

And it doesn't work. Maybe someone can tell me what i did wrong?

And the Questions:

1. How do i return "-1" or `null` for invalid arguments (sry if the translation is off) if i need to return an array?
2. Would the use of a `Scanner` be advised ? Never used it before so it might screw me over but heck..

I need to learn so I might as well start now!

Comment: What do you mean by an invalid argument?

Answer (score 0):

You asked 3 questions, which are actually two questions (questions1 and 2 having the same root cause) :

**1) Why does my code not work when I expect "System.in.read() like this : 250, 67, 365".**

**2) Should I use the Scanner class?**

Your issue here is that you want to read inputs of the *int* type. An *int* is a sequence of digits. It means that these digits must be read in order from the input, and then combined to create an actual int.

Some functions do that for you, some don't.

*System.in.read* reads individual characters, so it's not what you want. Worse, those individual characters are read as ASCII code, therefore if you input '9' then you'll get its ASCII code (57) and get confused.

The *Scanner* class does the reading from the input but then does error check and combines the input into the expected type, like this: 
     import java.util.Scanner;

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

**3) How do I return null for invalid arguments?**

From what I see, all your functions return arrays, which can have a null value. so you simply need to check that the argguments values are correct before returning. But you didn't say how they're supposed to be correct.